# spatie/sitemap wont install in laravel8 on godaddy server

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, sitemap.xml

i have made ecommerce website in laravel 8. i am trying to make sitemap.xml using spatie/sitemap package.
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap
but it does not install in my godaddy hosting.

the error is as follows:

```
****Using version ^5.8 for spatie/laravel-sitemap
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update spatie/laravel-sitemap
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - spatie/browsershot[3.33.1, ..., 3.40.2] require spatie/image ^1.5.3 -> satisfiable by spatie/image[1.5.3, ..., 1.10.2].
    - spatie/crawler[4.1.0, ..., 4.6.5] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0.1).
    - spatie/laravel-sitemap[5.9.0, ..., 5.9.2] require php ^7.4|^8.0 -> your php version (7.3.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - spatie/browsershot[3.40.3, ..., 3.44.0] require php ^7.4|^8.0 -> your php version (7.3.27) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - spatie/image[1.5.3, ..., 1.10.2] require ext-exif * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's exif extension.
    - spatie/browsershot[3.14.0, ..., 3.16.0] require symfony/process ^3.0 -> found symfony/process[v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v5.2.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - spatie/browsershot[3.16.1, ..., 3.26.0] require symfony/process ^3.0|^4.0 -> found symfony/process[v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev, v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v5.2.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - spatie/browsershot[3.26.1, ..., 3.33.0] require symfony/process ^4.2 -> found symfony/process[v4.2.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v5.2.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - spatie/laravel-sitemap 5.8.0 requires spatie/crawler ^4.1.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/crawler[4.1.0, ..., v4.x-dev].
    - spatie/crawler[4.6.6, ..., v4.x-dev] require spatie/browsershot ^3.14 -> satisfiable by spatie/browsershot[3.14.0, ..., 3.44.0].
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-sitemap ^5.8 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-sitemap[5.8.0, 5.9.0, 5.9.1, 5.9.2].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-json.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/zzzzzzz-pecl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.****
```

can anybody help me..i am struggling to get it done.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem was, in case anybody else is struggling.

1. You must have php version 7.4 or greater.
2. Install PHP extension [exif](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php)

Doing both these solved my problem.